# Could not connect to targat machine

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

**Problem Description:**

I am going to install MySQL server 5.7.11 (win32) into Windows server 2012. There are several network interface cards being installed in the server, and I am going to install several MySQL instances that bind to specific IP addresses. In short, I am going to install multiple MySQL instances that bind to different IP addresses in same machine.

I am managed to install the first MySQL instance and able to start the service successfully. But when using MySQL Workbench 6.3.6 CE (win32) to connect to the instance, I am getting the following error messages.

> RuntimeError: Could not initialize WMI interface:
>   Workbench.wmiOpenSession(): Could not connect to target machine.

**Installer:**

- mysql-5.7.11-win32.zip (no install)
- mysql-workbench-community-6.3.6-win32-noinstall.zip

**my.ini configuration:**

```
# For advice on how to change settings please see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-configuration-defaults.html
# *** DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE. It's a template which will be copied to the
# *** default location during install, and will be replaced if you
# *** upgrade to a newer version of MySQL.

[mysqld]

# Remove leading # and set to the amount of RAM for the most important data
# cache in MySQL. Start at 70% of total RAM for dedicated server, else 10%.
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 128M

# Remove leading # to turn on a very important data integrity option: logging
# changes to the binary log between backups.
# log_bin

# These are commonly set, remove the # and set as required.
basedir=D:/apps/mysql-5.7.11
datadir=D:/apps/nrcc/data
port=3306
bind-address=10.82.95.2


# Remove leading # to set options mainly useful for reporting servers.
# The server defaults are faster for transactions and fast SELECTs.
# Adjust sizes as needed, experiment to find the optimal values.
# join_buffer_size = 128M
# sort_buffer_size = 2M
# read_rnd_buffer_size = 2M 

sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES
```

**MySQL Workbench configuration:**

Please see the image below for the configurations. When Workbench is opened and click on the Server Status or Options File, it will prompt to enter a username and password. But then followed by the error messages.

[Workbench configurations and error messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/POFz7.png)

I thought it was because my user do not have WMI permission, so I followed this link [Creating a user with Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI) permissions](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSTFXA_6.3.0/com.ibm.itm.doc_6.3/builder/ab_config_wmi_user.htm) to configure the user, but it still not working. Note that the user is in the local administrators group.

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to remotely connect to my MySQL server from MySQL Workbench running on another server (my application server), although the problem still exist if I do it on the same server.

I have tested that by granting WMI permission to the user in MySQL server, the connection works as intended. The following list shows what I have done:

1. In MySQL server, add on following groups to the user.

   - Distributed COM Users
   - Performance Log Users
   - Remote Desktop Users
2. Configure the WMI namespace security assignments

   > a. Go to Windows Start > Run....
   >   b. Enter wmimgmt.msc and click OK.
   >   c. Right-click WMI Control (Local) and select Properties.
   >   d. Click the Security tab.
   >   e. Click Security.
   >   f. Click Add.
   >   g. Click Advanced.
   >   h. Click Find Now.
   >   i. Select the new user account, and click OK until you return to the Security for Root window.
   >   j. Click Advanced and select the newly added user account.
   >   k. Click Edit.
   >   l. From the Apply to: menu selection, select This namespace and subnamespaces.
   >   m. In Execute Methods, verify that Enable Account, Remote Enable, and Read Security are selected.
   >   n. Click OK until you return to the wmimgmt window.
   >   o. Select File > Exit to exit the wmimgmt window.

Comment: How to do point 1 ?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same problem and it seems Workbench has a small bug. For local WMI management the only way I  could get it to work was with 127.0.0.1 But not if I used a DNS/NetBios name or local network address.

I checked with powershell  Get-WmiObject and it will return information with any ComputerName locally i.e. 127.0.0.1,192.168.1.126,mycomputername,mycomputername.domain.com.... So I am  guessing it has to do with the WorkBench query to wmi not being correct in some manner?

PS:
Get-WmiObject  -Query "select * from win32_service where name='MySql8'" -ComputerName 127.0.0.1,192.168.1.126,....(etc)( to check that wmi is working locally )

So in this scenario I just used the loop-back locally to manage the instance with native windows wmi.

Hopefully this saves someone the 2+ hours I just wasted on this exact problem !

Answer (score 0):

This WMI error has nothing to do with MySQL. [MySQL Workbench uses Windows Management Instrumentation](http://mysqlworkbench.org/2010/12/mysql-workbench-manage-mysql-on-windows-servers-the-windows-way/) (WMI) to manage servers locally or remotely in a Windows based environment. WMI is available on all Windows versions and enabled on all customer Windows, but might require extra configuration on server OSes.

So, your best bet is to search how to enable + configure WMI on Windows 2012.

Comment: You are right, I found that it was the WMI permission issue. Although I still cannot connect it locally from the MySQL server, but I can connect it from another server.